# How to show push notification while app is in running state in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

Though till Swift 3 we used `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]` method its working fine, but in Swift 4 its not working. Does anyone have any idea about it ?

Comment: There is no change in this method related to swift version, neither has anything changed in the recent iOS versions. It should work seamlessly. Consider posting your code that once worked but doesn't work now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For displaying notification while app is in foreground, use the following method.**

```
// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) 
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

According to apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1), you can display notification while app is running

[image]